# Spring cloud function is not invoked on AWS lambda

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, spring-cloud-function

I have a function that needs to run on lambda taking an SQSEvent as input. What i see is that, the FunctionInvoker is able to detect the function, but the apply method is not invoked. What might be the issue with configuration here?

MyApplication.java

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableFeignClients
public class MyApplication implements ApplicationContextInitializer<GenericApplicationContext> {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(GenericApplicationContext context) {

        context.registerBean("myFunction", FunctionRegistration.class,
                () -> new FunctionRegistration<>(new MyFunction()).type(FunctionTypeUtils.functionType(SQSEvent.class, String.class)));

    }
}
```

MyFunction.java

```
@Slf4j @Data
public class MyFunction implements Function<SQSEvent, String> {

    
    @Override
    public String apply(SQSEvent sqsEvent) {
        log.info("Received event: " + sqsEvent);
                doSomething();
                return "success";

   }
}
```

template.yaml

```
  MyLambdaService:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ...
      Handler: org.springframework.cloud.function.adapter.aws.FunctionInvoker::handleRequest
      ....
      Environment:
        Variables:
          FUNCTION_NAME: myFunction
          MAIN_CLASS: com.myorg.my_service.MyApplication
```

The logs I get: (both in sam local invoke as well as deployed lambda)

```
 2023-06-26 14:09:55  INFO  AWSLambda - Started AWSLambda in 38.986 seconds (process running for 101.709)
    2023-06-26 14:09:55  INFO  FunctionInvoker - Locating function: 'null'
    2023-06-26 14:09:55  INFO  FunctionInvoker - Located function: 'myFunction'
    2023-06-26 14:09:55 a77f799b-0a4a-4311-b9b7-74bd6c963c6f INFO  AWSLambdaUtils - Received: { ...test event content ...}
    END RequestId: a77f799b-0a4a-4311-b9b7-74bd6c963c6f
    REPORT RequestId: a77f799b-0a4a-4311-b9b7-74bd6c963c6f  Init Duration: 0.16 ms  Duration: 109589.64 ms  Billed Duration: 109590 ms      Memory Size: 512 MB     Max Memory Used: 512 MB
```